# Как получить все значения массива в другом методе и распечатать их?

Tags: java, массивы, intellij-idea, for, return

Как вывести на экран в методе Main значения массива patientsTemperature, в формате "Температуры пациентов: 36.7 38.95 34.7 32.41"?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float[] temperatureData = Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures(10);
    }
}

public class Hospital {

    public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {

        float[] patientsTemperature = new float[patientsCount];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < patientsCount; i++) {
            patientsTemperature[i] = Math.round(((float) (Math.random() * 8) + 32) * 100) / (float) 100.0;
            //System.out.println(patientsTemperature[i]);
        }

        return patientsTemperature;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема вашего кода?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hospital obj_Hospital = new Hospital();
        obj_Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures()
        float[] temperatureData = obj_Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures(10);
    }
}

public class Hospital {

    public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {

        float[] patientsTemperature = new float[patientsCount];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < patientsCount; i++) {
            patientsTemperature[i] = Math.round(((float) (Math.random() * 8) + 32) * 100) / (float) 100.0;
            System.out.print(patientsTemperature[i]);
        }

        return patientsTemperature;
    }
}
```

Comment: в методе Main нужно получить, и при этом метод находится в другом классе, так не выйдет

Comment: @ArturKnyazev в таком случае необходимо создать объект класса, я изменил код, попробуйте